# issue to read an input with BufferedReader

Tags: java

I've got a problem with a `BufferedReader` and an `InputStreamReader` which is closed. When I try to read an input with the `readLine()` method, the console says "Stream closed" at line 5

Here is the code :

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
System.out.println("Souhaitez-vous ajouter une matiere?");
String reponse0=in.readLine();
if(reponse0=="oui" || reponse0=="yes") {
        Ajouter_matiere.ajouter_matiere(liste0);
} else if(reponse0=="non" || reponse0=="no") {
        System.out.println("Ok!");
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your error, but strings are compared with `equals`, not `==`. So `if(reponse0.equals("oui") || reponse0.equals("yes"))` or, even better, `"oui"equals(response0)` etc...

Comment: Hmm, I can't replicate your issue, your code executes for me without issue.

Comment: Have you perhaps closed `System.in` previously in your code?

Comment: Also, wouldn't it be easier to use a scanner for this? As in `Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); String response0 = s.nextLine();`

Comment: What is `liste0`? And yes....use the String#equals() method instead of `==` to compare strings for equality, for example: `reponse0.equals("oui")` or `reponse0.equalsIgnoreCase("oui")`.

Comment: The message "Stream closed" should be part of an IOException, which will have a stack trace. Please add the entire stack trace to your question.